# Uninstalling Texlive 2017 from windows 10

Tags: texlive-2017

I just want to remove Tex Live 2017 from my Win 10, it does not normally show in "Add or remove programs" list.

Comment: Just find the directory where it is installed, and delete it. On my PC it's in C:\texlive\2017. Tex Live doesn't do anything "sneaky" like playing with the Windows Registry, installing stuff in Windows directories, etc. If you really want to get rid of every last trace of it, delete it from your environment PATH variable as well, but the overhead of *not* doing that is completely negligible.